# Python Lists , FIles, For Loops, Index

Tags: python, list, file, for-loop

I am comfused with how to tackle this, I have done the first few parts by opening the file, converting it to a list and completing the first prompt but now I dont really understand how to do this. The prompt for this part is:

All Words that Have a User Chosen Letter in a Specified Location
This task builds on the first task, but instead of the letter appearing anywhere in the word, you need to output every word that has the letter in a very specific location. The user provides a single letter, and what location in the word it appears in. Make sure you give clear instructions to the user on how to denote the letter location (is the first letter 0? 1? something else? They won't know what your program expects unless you tell them).

All Words that Have a User Specified Number of Vowels
Supposedly the best way to play Wordle is to use a word with lots of vowels as your first guess. For this task you will let the user choose how many vowels they want in their word, and then output all words that have that number of vowels. This task is the hardest of the required tasks, so think about it after you've reasoned through the others. Recall that vowels in English are the letters a, e, i, o, and u.

```
import os.path
def name_file():
    # asking user name of file
    file_name = input("What is the name of the file to read the names from?")
    while not os.path.exists(file_name):
        print("This file does not exist")
        file_name = input("What is the name of the file to read the names from?")
    return file_name
name_file()

file_opener = open("5letterwords.txt","r")
read_line_by_line = file_opener.readlines()

word_list = []

for line in read_line_by_line:
    word_list.append(line.strip())
print(word_list)

letter = input("Pick a letter of your choosing and every word with that letter will be outputted:")
for word in word_list:
    if letter in word:
        print(word)

letter2 = input("Pick another letter and every word with that letter will be outputted")
location = input("Pick what location you want the letter to be in from 1-5")
for word in word_list:
    if letter2 in word and :
```

I currently have that done and starting from the variable letter 2 is where I start wrking on the prompt but I am clueless as to what to do. I would like some hints and tips on how to do this, i've been working on it for almost 3 weeks now and not much progress

Answer (score 0):

I think there are three steps to your second task:

1. Get the input letter and index.
2. Iterate over the list of words.
3. Check each word to see if the letter is in the desired index and print the word if so.

You have part of number 1 and all of number 2 handled already.

To finish the first step, you need to convert your `location` value, which is a numeric string, into an integer and make sure it matches the zero-indexing of Python strings.

For the third step, you need to index your each word string with the converted index value you got from the user. You *might* want some error handling here, to correctly report invalid indexes, but since that isn't specifically called out in your requirements something minimal might serve (e.g. print an error message and quit). The comparison of the indexed letter to the input letter should be trivial after that.

Comment: Okay, I converted the location value to an integer, how do I use the input im getting from the user (letter and position) and use that  to print every word with the letter they gave me in the specific position. I have an input that asks the user to pick somewhere from 1-5 and in my program I know this means 0-4 for each letter in the list but I don't know how to put it all together